# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, h2

Product.java --

```
package com.niit.model;


import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) //Automatically generate value for Id using sequence
private int id;
private String productname;
private String productDescription;
private int quantity;
private double price;
@ManyToOne
private Category category;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getProductname() {
    return productname;
}
public void setProductname(String productname) {
    this.productname = productname;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}
public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}
```

Category.java--

```
package com.niit.model;

import java.util.List;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String categoryname;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Product> products;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCategoryname() {
    return categoryname;
}
public void setCategoryname(String categoryname) {
    this.categoryname = categoryname;
}
}
```

Internal error 500 encountered :

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.handleNullValue(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:111)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: use Integer instead of int, it will resolve your Issue

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory: you can't declare a primitive to be null, 
for example : private int id = null; will not compile. So instead of using int use Integer and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thing is the primitive int id is taken as a primary key for a backend project and it is not initialized as 0 or null in the Product class. By logic it should have a default 0 value initially before it is updated in the frontend. But on runtime, the int value is apparently null. It's reading the datatype as something it is not.

Comment: @RichaDey, when you will save product class in your DB Id annotation automatically generate an integer value and store in DB, i case if you will call the entity, before it store in DB it will return null because table is created but it doesn't have any row it will not map to your entity's int value, If still you didn't get feel free to post your use cases

Comment: Or how you have written in controller, because sometimes may be you have taken an Integer in controller that can also create an Issue